# Create folder structure on a networked drive

Tags: applescript, directory, structure, finder

I'm trying to create a folder structure using applescript. This code works great locally, but when I try it on a networked drive it returns "Can't get <> "test" of application "Finder".

This is the code I have

```
 tell application "Finder"
set campaignName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Campaign Name:" default answer "Campaign Name")
tell application "Finder" to set currentDirectory to target of Finder window 1
make new folder at currentDirectory with properties {name:campaignName}
make new folder at folder campaignName with properties {name:"a-creative"}
make new folder at folder "a-creative" of folder campaignName with properties {name:"a-assets-from-client"}
make new folder at folder "a-creative" of folder campaignName with properties {name:"b-art-director-files"}
make new folder at folder "a-creative" of folder campaignName with properties {name:"c-for-production"}
make new folder at folder "a-creative" of folder campaignName with properties {name:"d-developer-notes"}
make new folder at folder "b-art-director-files" of folder "a-creative" of folder campaignName with properties {name:"PSD"}
make new folder at folder "b-art-director-files" of folder "a-creative" of folder campaignName with properties {name:"storyboard"} 
 end tell
```

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I'm new to using applescript.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set campaignName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Campaign Name:" default answer "Campaign Name")
    tell application "Finder" to set currentDirectory to target of Finder window 1
    set projectFolderRoot to make new folder at currentDirectory with properties {name:campaignName}

    set aCreativeRoot to make new folder at projectFolderRoot with properties {name:"a-creative"}
    set bArtDirectorRoot to make new folder at aCreativeRoot with properties {name:"b-art-director-files"}
    make new folder at aCreativeRoot with properties {name:"c-for-production"}
    make new folder at aCreativeRoot with properties {name:"d-developer-notes"}

    make new folder at bArtDirectorRoot with properties {name:"PSD"}
    make new folder at bArtDirectorRoot with properties {name:"storyboard"}
end tell
```